# mysql-connector-python 2.0.1-1 confilct with python-mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql

When I was installing `mysql-connector-python 2.0.1-1` (http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/) on Ubuntu 14.04, the Software Center complaints about confilcting with `python-mysql.connector`. Should I uninstall `python-mysql.connector`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into creating a virtual environment (like pyenv or virtualenv) for the project that requires that particular version. That way you can have both versions without them conflicting with each other. It might take longer that uninstalling / reinstalling, but on the long term it is a good habit to form to prevent these kind of issues.