# Django: how to install mysql/connector python with pip3

Tags: mysql-python, mysql-connector

I am working on projects based on Django 1.7 and Python 3.4. However, I had problems installing MySQL/Connector Python with pip3.

According to [this document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/databases/), MySQL/Connector Python supports Python 3. I used to install MySQL-python in Python with command `pip install MySQL-python`.

[This download page](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/) only provides .deb files for installation on Ubuntu (btw, the installation also has [conflict problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26572960/mysql-connector-python-2-0-1-1-confilct-with-python-mysql-connector))

I tried to install with:

```
pip3 install mysql-connector-python --allow-external mysql-connector-python
```

No error messages. But when I run the Django app, I got the following error message:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

Question:
So, how do I install MySQL/Connector Python into a virtual environment with pip3? Or is it supposed to be installed into the system, instead of a virtual environment?

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: I re-edited the question

Comment: Please post the content of the *DATABASES* section of your `settings.py` file

Comment: DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': '<db_name>',
        'USER': '<user_name>',
        'PASSWORD': '<user_password>',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}

Comment: BTW, I tried to change 'ENGING' to 'django.connector.mysql', but Django complaints "No module named 'django.connector'
".

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The 'Engine' should be 'mysql.connector.django'. It works. Sorry about it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you read [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers), you will see that [the native MySQLdb driver](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.4) doesn't support Python 3. You have two options:

**A mysqldb fork**

There is a fork that supports Python 3. Read [its Github repo](https://github.com/clelland/MySQL-for-Python-3) to know how to install with your system. For Ubuntu do `apt-get install python-mysqldb`

**MySQL connector**

Install from venv as you did with `pip install mysql-connector-python --allow-external mysql-connector-python`. Then read [their documentation for Django](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-django-backend.html) and modify your `settings.py` file to have it like:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'user_data',
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'priv4te',
        'OPTIONS': {
          'autocommit': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Pay attention to the connector value `mysql.connector.django` :-)

Comment: Python-mysqldb installed, but no luck.

Comment: This stopped working. Now I'm using mysqlclient. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22419210/django-and-mysql-problems-on-mavericks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22419210/django-and-mysql-problems-on-mavericks)

Comment: @Lucio please, update your answer:
`mysql-connector-python` >= 8.0.13 has a bug, making it impossible to work with Django: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30469  
As a workaround, add `'use_pure': True` to the `'OPTIONS'`.

Answer (score 4):

The version of mysql-connector that pip installs doesn't work with Django 1.8. There is a fixed version on github. The command to install from there is

```
pip install --allow-all-external git+git://github.com/multiplay/mysql-connector-python
```

That one works with Django 1.8.