# Justifying Non-Standard Python 3 MySQL Connector Use

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x

I am creating a project using Django + Python 3.4. However, according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573984/django-how-to-install-mysql-connector-python-with-pip3), the standard MySQL connector for Python does not support the language's third release (which I'm having a difficult time believing, but that's beside the point).

Ultimately, my question is whether or not it is justifiable to use a non-standard connector fork (such as that which is presented in the linked question above) over downgrading to Python 2.x. For example, are there any significant security issues with using the forked connector instead of waiting for an official release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL Connector/Python is not bundled with Django, but it is made by Oracle. So I'm not sure if it should be considered an unofficial fork.

I'm using it with an old mySQL database, python 3.4 and django 1.7. The only problem I've noticed is that sometimes the error messages are a bit wonky.

Installation is very easy:

```
pip install mysql-connector-python --allow-external mysql-connector-python
```

Comment: This gives a more concrete reason as to why a specific connector should be used. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I have been using the mysql-connector-python connector for several months without issue.  This is using Python 3.4.2 and Django-1.7.1.

It actually works much better than the git fork someone else did of the python 2 connector.

My opinion, don't downgrade to python 2 - This is a solid connector in my experience.

Comment: Also you may have figured this out already, but you need to set the database engine to `mysql.connector.django` in settings.py